# Creating a new environment containing a tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, environments

I would like to create a new environment in order to ease the process of making plots. It should be able to something like this:

```
\begin{graph}
\addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=1000]{x)};
\end{graph}
```

Thus the axis is predefined, and all I have to is add the plot that I want.

So far i have tried the following without any succes

```
\newenvironment{graph}[3]{\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[
width=8cm,  xlabel={  $ #1 $ },ylabel={$ #2 $},axis x line=left, axis y line=left, 
title={$#3 $}, xmin = 0,xmax = 10,ymin = 0,ymax = 10, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty] 
{\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: Note that such an approach is incompatible with `\usetikzlibrary{external}` - just for you to know. The `external` lib requires that `\end{tikzpicture}` is "in sight without expansion" as soon as `\begin{tikzpicture}` is evaluated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You define the environment with three arguments but call it with none. This can’t work.
Furthermore there was a closing brace missing in the definition. It would be more flexible if you use only one optional argument (see `{othergraph}` definition), to pass options directly to the `{axis}` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newenvironment{graph}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=8cm,
        xlabel={$#1$},
        ylabel={$#2$},
        axis x line=left,
        axis y line=left,
        title={$#3 $},
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 10,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
    ]
}
{
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newenvironment{othergraph}[1][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=8cm,
        axis x line=left,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 10,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        #1
    ]
}
{
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{graph}{x}{f(x)}{f(x)=x}
    \addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=1000] {x};
\end{graph}

\begin{othergraph}[
    title={My Graph},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$f(x)$},
]
    \addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=1000] {x};
\end{othergraph}
\end{document}
```

Btw. Indenting and line-breaking code and definitions helps to find missing braces ;-)

Comment: I would avoid having the title in math mode, though.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Me too, but thats how the OP defined it …

Comment: Thanks a lot.
One additional question:
When i draw a function the node saying which function it is, is not always showing. How can I let latex know that I want the node placed at the point where the graph exits the plot?

Comment: @Euler: You can use the node `(current plot end)` in a path like `\node at (current plot end) [right] {$f(x)$};` right after `\addplott ...` but you must add the option `clip=false` for the axis environment …

Answer (score 8):

Tobi has given you the exact answer to your question, but you might like to see another approach.

One of the huge benefits of [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) and [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) is that they allow the user to create *styles* in the preamble which can be used throughout the document. In particular, you can use the following code in your preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        width=8cm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis x line=left,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 10,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
    }
}
```

This will be the default that is applied to *every* `axis` environment. You can, of course, override any or all of these settings locally; for example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title={My Graph},
            ylabel={$f(x)$},
        ]
        \addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=1000] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Using this approach is encouraged- it eases code readability, and is immediately obvious to the reader that you are using the [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) package; 'hiding' the `axis` and `tikzpicture` environments within your own custom environment may confuse some readers in the future.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        width=8cm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis x line=left,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 10,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title={My Graph},
            ylabel={$f(x)$},
        ]
        \addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=1000] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```