# My personal TikZ template to be easily changed

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, plot, foreach

Every time I need to plot a simple function (eg. a parabola), I use a self-made TikZ template that is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \newcommand{\mygrid}{\draw [color=lightgray,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (-4.5,-4.5) grid (4.5,4.5);}
 \newcommand{\Xaxis}{ \draw [->] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node [above] {$x$};\foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\scriptstyle\x$};}
 \newcommand{\Yaxis}{ \draw [->] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5) node [left]  {$y$};\foreach \y in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left]  {$\scriptstyle\y$};}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
   \mygrid
   \Xaxis
   \Yaxis
   \clip(-4.5,-4.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);
   \draw [very thick,blue,smooth,domain=-4.5:4.5] plot (\x,{(\x)^2-2*\x-3});
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

As you can see, the graph is plotted and clipped in a range from -4.5 to 4.5 for the x axis and the y axis, as well.

If I need to expand or shrink the plot ranges, I have to do it manually.
Any advice to do it in a easier way than the "Find & replace" way?

I have an idea:

```
\newcommand{\myplot}[2]{\mygrid\Xaxis\Yaxis}
```

But I know I will find troubles in the `\foreach` instance for sure.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you looked at the `pgfplots` package? You might also like, for example, [Creating a new environment containing a tikz environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160067)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the PGFPlots package (which you already load) for this. It makes for much more maintainable code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    max space between ticks=20, % This is one way of getting a tick for every integer
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin=-4.5, xmax=4.5, % The range over which the x axis is drawn
    ymin=-4.5, ymax=4.5, % The range over which the y axis is drawn
    domain=-4:4,         % The range over which the function is evaluated
    grid=both,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$
]
 \addplot [very thick, blue, smooth] {x^2-2*x-3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, this is a great solution! I created a template based on it. Don't you think it needs a row like "scale=1.5,"? Seems a too little picture to me. Thanks in advice